# AWS application load balancer - access from private vpc and limited allowed public ips

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a shared AWS application load balancer that serves environments within the vpc. I also want to access those environments (https) from some public IPs which are in the allowed list of the security group attached to the load balancer.
How should I do this?

Here is what I did:

1. Created a public-facing load balancer with its instances in the private subnet.
2. The load balancer has security rules to allow  ingress from 2 public ips and from the internal subnet 10.10.0.0/16
3. The DNS resolves to the load balancer.

This is obviously not working from within the vpc. nslookup shows that the load balancer end point resolves to public ips.

Is there a way that I can have both private and public IPs for the load balancer. I would then maybe need to create Route 53 entries which do separate internal and external DNS look up

Comment: You generally need to create two load balancers, one public and one private, pointed at the same targets, for this scenario. You wouldn't be able to maintain the private IPs of a public load balancer in Route53 because they could change at any moment.

Comment: Is there a way by which amazon can provide me with different ns for the same load balancer - one for public and the other private. Any other way, apart from creating different load balancers (and incurring extra cost) ?

Comment: No, if there was I would certainly have mentioned that. Unfortunately they don't really provide a way at this time to have a load balancer with both internal and external resolvable DNS names.